# java.awt.HeadlessException on a Java WebService

Tags: java, web-services

I try to to open a Browser with a URL if a WebServer is called. The WebServer works fine on a Tomcat7 and I created it with Eclipse. I tested this Code on the Eclipse Server and every thing is ok and a new Browser with the URL is open.

```
public java.lang.String register(java.lang.String username, java.lang.String password) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
    try{
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://google.de"));
    }catch(Exception e){ 
           StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
           e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
           String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
           username = exceptionAsString;
    }  
    return "NEW TOKEN:"+password + username;
}
```

But if I deploy the code as a war-file to the "real" TomcatServer I get this error: (the webservice is ok and i become the return value, but the new Browser is not open)
The Error is thrown, because the desktop is not supported `Desktop.isDesktopSupported() == false` on the "real" Server

```
java.awt.HeadlessException at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:124)
....
```

My question is now, why I get this error when everything works fine on the test system and how could I resolve this problem ?

Comment: What is ur target run-time system ? Is that *Windows* or *Linux* or something else ?

Comment: I have updated my answer providing **an alternative solution to support multiple target environments & remove HeadlessException.** Have a look at it.

Comment: it is a WindowsServer 2008 R2; I will try your alternavtive solution

Comment: I have also added another link which has solution to problem with **windows server 2008 R2 + RDP**. Have a look at it too. I hope it helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i did not resolve my problem. I found an other way, I give the URL back to the client and he open it. The Problem ist that the Server has no UI-Enviorment.

Answer (score 0):

When you test it locally it works because the local environment has a UI. I suspect the "real" tomcat doesn't have a UI, so can't perform any UI related tasks.

Why are you launching a UI on a server that nobody is ever going to see or interact with? What are you trying to achieve? You need to code a non interactive way of getting the task done.

Maybe you could also check out some of the other questions on here about `HeadlessException`.

Comment: my goal is that is somebody call the webservice he is redirect to a  specific WebSite (in this example just google.de), or is there a better way to call a website out of a web service?

Answer (score 0):

From the Java doc [HeadlessException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html)

```
HeadlessException : Thrown when code that is dependent on a keyboard, display, or 
mouse is called in an environment that does not support a keyboard, display, or mouse.
```

You are calling `Desktop.getDesktop()` method & it is not supporting your run-time environment. Look at [Desktop getDesktop()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#getDesktop())

Instead of checking

```
Desktop.isDesktopSupported() == false
```

you can use this

```
if(!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
    //do someting
}
```

**Solution to support multiple target environment & get rid of HeadlessException :**

[Desktop API is not supported on the current platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004150/desktop-api-is-not-supported-on-the-current-platform) in this post **@MightyPork** has good workaround to support different OSs & remove HeadlessException. You must have a look at this.

**@Balazs Gunics** is also facing the **same problem** with **windows server 2008 R2 + RDP** & he **got the solution with @Andrea Turri answer** given at [Opening an URL from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348463/opening-an-url-from-java/12348510#12348510). You can also try this.